# Relations. Can they be expanded to more than 2 arguments?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

As binary relation (at least with Kuratowski definition) is set of ordered pairs, can relations be set of ordered n's?
And if they can be, what is domain, and counter domain in such relation, for example with ordered 5's?
And more, can be restriction and composition defined for such relations, and how?

More generally, i know the definition and properties and operations for binary relations, and i wonder if there is a way to expand this definition to n-argument relations.

Comment: Ordered $n$ tuple $(a_1,...,a_n)$ is just $\{\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}\mid0<k\leq n\}$.

Comment: Yes. Search for n-ary relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like a binary relation is a subset of $X \times Y$, an $n$-ary relation is a set of $n$-tuples from a product $X_1 \times \ldots X_n$. See [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) for notions of composition etc. (joins). It has actually been studied in connection with relational databases..

Most maths concerns itself with binary relations ((partial) orders, equivalence relations, functions, incidence relations) and not so much with the higher order ones, as can be seen from examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation).

Comment: "Most maths concerns itself with binary relations ... and not so much with the higher order ones"  It may be worth noting that the $n$ product $X\times X\times X\times.... \times X \times X$ and an $n$tuple $(a_1, ...,a_{n-1},a_n)$ is for all practical purposes the same as the $2$ product $\small{[X\times X\times...\times X]}\large{\times X}$ and that ordered pair $\big(\small (a_1,.....,a_{n-1}\small ),a_n\big)$ so higher order relations are essentially just binary relations "bootstrapped" up.

Comment: ... or *finitely* higher orders, I should say... countably Infinite cartesian products and countably infinite tuples (otherwise known as .... sequences...) are a completely different story.

Comment: @fleablood but we don't "compose" sets of sequences, usually, e.g. A single sequences is hardly an infinitary relation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @Don Thousand and @Henno Brandsma have pointed out, $n$-ary relations are just subsets of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.  Henno metioned that they don't get studied much in mathematics, but that doesn't mean they don't get studied at all.

Relational databases (like SQL) use a [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model).  Essentially, if you have a huge table of data, the rows of the table represent $n$-tuples in your relation.  If you had a table where the first column was name, the second column was age, and the third column was weight, the tuple (John Doe, 37, 180) as a row of your data could represent the statement "John Doe is 37 years old and weighs 180 pounds".  In general, $(x, y, z)$ would mean "Person $x$ is $y$ years old and weighs $z$ pounds".